# integrate Twilio IP messaging with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twilio

i want to integrate in Twilio IP messaging in my web app through angularjs.
this is how i can start a private chat

```
messagingClient.createChannel({
uniqueName: 'secret',
friendlyName: 'Private Chat Channel',
type: 'private'}).then(function(channel) {
console.log('Created private channel:');
console.log(channel);});
```

can any one guide me how to call IP messaging Rest API. Thanks for support

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like it might be helpful for you to run through the [IP Messaging JavaScript Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/quickstart-js).  This will take you through setting up a simple IP Messaging application in the browser.

The steps in brief are:

1. Generate a service instance which you can do from the [developer console](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/ip-messaging/services) or using the REST API
2. Grab your [Twilio Account SID](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/ip-messaging) and generate a new [app key](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/ip-messaging/dev-tools/api-keys) and [app secret](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/ip-messaging/dev-tools/api-keys)
3. Set up a server-side endpoint that can generate and return an access token.  [Here is an example in Node](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/ipm-quickstart-node/archive/master.zip), but we also have examples in PHP, Java, C#, Ruby and Python linked from the quickstart.
4. Add the IP Messaging JavaScript SDK your application
5. Initiate the IP Messaging client using the access token
6. Create and/or join a channel
7. Send messages to it.

Hope that helps.